# move div to highest point of viewport on click

Tags: javascript, click, position, viewport, move

On a webpage with hundreds of div elements I need to be able to click on anyone and have the window scroll (up or down) so that the div then appears at the top of the viewport.

In other words: how to have the window scroll when an element is clicked, so that this element then appears on top of the viewport?

Can Element.scrollIntoView() do this (and how)?

Comment: You can give `fixed` position to the `div` and then position it to the top of viewport.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want to do (click on the button to see):

```js
$("button").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("sivola");
});
```

```css
.sivola {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr><hr>
<button>130 Martin Garrix si volaaa</button>
```

Comment: That's assuming he is using jQuery though.

Comment: Nope, it can be done without jquery in the same way, i just wrote it with jquery cause it's faster for me ^^

Comment: Sure. Just wanted to point it out in case he tried to use this code directly, then wonder why it would not work :)

Comment: Hey thanks for that! The only thing is with 'position: fixed', the div will stay on top of the viewport indefinitely. Is there a way to only have the window scroll so that the button doesn't actually have to move? I think I need to rephrase my original question!

Comment: I don't undertstamd

Answer (score 0):

Assign classnames to your `div`.

One (standard behavior) will contain your standard CSS properties, and the other (the one you will use to reposition your `div` on top of the viewport) will have something like

```
className {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     ...
}
```

Just assign this classname to your div on whichever event you want to trigger the `fixed` position on.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the top of the document to 0px and animate it.

```
 $('scrollToTopBtn').click(function(e){
        $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop':'0'});
        e.preventDefault();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution! Use the JS below to achieve this.
Note that "theOffset.top - 1" is the position relative to the top of the viewport and "100" is the delay after click in ms

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$(".elementclass").click(function(){
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                theOffset = $(self).offset();
                $('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: theOffset.top - 1 });
            }, 100);
        });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and easy.

```
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        var element = document.getElementById('myDiv');
        element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
});
```

or inline you can try when button is clicked:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('nd').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});">Scroll to Div</button>
```